# OneToOne Lazy always fetch child

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, lazy-loading

I have the following `@OneToOne` relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

private Basket basket;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true,mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    public Basket getBasket() {
        return basket;
    }

    public void setBasket(Basket basket) {
        this.basket = basket;
    }

//all other proerties are ommited and none relevant. 
}
```

Now the basket class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BASKET")
public class Basket implements Serializable {

private User user;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
//all other proerties are ommited and none relevant. 
}
```

Now I'm trying to fetch User object using HQL in object which has Spring Transaction manager using AOP:

```
public User getUser(String param1,String param2) {
    Session session = this.sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
    String queryString = "from objects.User user where user.param1=:param1 and user.param2=:param2";
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString); 
    query.setString("param1", param1);
    query.setString("param2", param2);
    User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
    return user;
}
```

but I see that Basket is also fetched although it's Lazy:

```
Hibernate: select user0......
Hibernate: select basket0.....
```

Why?

Comment: Could you post the whole query of the second SELECT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a one-to-one normally represents highly cohesive objects and is fetched using a join by default, so there's little reason *not* to fetch both user and basket. I'm not sure why you're seeing two separate selects. I believe that should only happen if you tell it specifically to fetch using a select instead of a join. [This article](http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2007/08/12/investigating-hibernate-relationships-one-to-one/) does a good job of analyzing a one-to-one relationship. It might help you out.